# Why is pip failing to uninstall pytz on ubuntu?

Tags: python, pip

> I am unsure if this is the correct stack exchange

I am installing a requirements file in a python virtual environment.

```
which pip
/var/www/my_site/prices/env/bin/pip
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I had ubuntu 16.04 but recently did a `do-release-upgrade` to `18.04` then `20.04`

Current version: `Ubuntu 20.04.4`

Existing distribution tz packages:

```
$ sudo apt list python*tz*
Listing... Done
python-tz/focal,focal 2019.3-1 all
python3-fitz/focal 1.16.11-1 amd64
python3-tz/focal,focal,now 2019.3-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-tzlocal/focal,focal 2.1~b1-2 all
```

For some reason pip is now attempting to uninstall the distribution level package of `pytz` - that is outside of the virtual environment.
This breaks my pip requirements install process and exits with a non-zero status.
Why are the packages of the distributions python mixing with my virtualenv - and how can I fix this?

```
  Attempting uninstall: pytz
    Found existing installation: pytz 2019.3
    Not uninstalling pytz at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /var/www/my_site/prices/env
    Can't uninstall 'pytz'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Running setup.py install for peewee ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

Comment: is this the only package `pip` is installing in the wrong place? did you modify `$PYTHONPATH` in any way on your own?

Comment: I don't think I modified it. Here is it `PYTHONPATH=:/home/staging:/usr/bin/python:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. Yes is is the only package so far.

Comment: If I remove /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages from the `$PYTHONPATH` the requirements install works. How can I ensure this happens automatically if this is the fix?